# LINQ to SQL Transaction when Transaction is type Table<Transaction>

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions

I'm attempting to create a transaction to wrap around several LINQ to SQL SubmitChanges() calls.

### Code

```
System.Data.Common.DbTransaction trans = null;

using (DbContext context = new DbContext())
{
    context.Connection.Open()
    trans = context.Connection.BeginTransaction();

    context.Transaction = trans; // <-- ERROR HERE: Cannot be done!

    .... // Several calls to delete objects with context.SaveChanges()

    trans.Commit();
}
```

### Problem

In our database schema (which pre-dates me, and is heavily tied into the application), we have a table called `Transaction`.

This means that the Transaction property in the code above is not actually an IDbTransaction type, and I am unable to assign the trans object to context.Transaction. `context.Transaction` is actually of type `Table<Transaction>`.

## Question

How can I assign a transaction to my context, given the currently unchangeable fact that I have a table named Transaction?

Although I'm familiar with LINQ to SQL, this is the first time for me using a Transaction around multiple calls, so I'm also ready to accept that I may not be doing this the right way in the first place, and that the conflicting table name may not even be an issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Transaction` property from `DataContext` is being hidden by your `DbContext` class, just cast:

```
((DataContext) context).Transaction = trans;
```

That way `Transaction` is resolved by the compiler to `DataContext.Transaction` instead of `DbContext.Transaction`.

Alternatively you could use a separate variable, which could be useful if you have several such calls to make:

```
DataContext vanillaContext = context;
vanillaContext.Transaction = trans;
```

(I have no idea whether or not this is the right way to use the transaction by the way - it's just the way to get around your naming collision.)

Comment: Damn it! I had a feeling it was something like this, I had attempted casting it to my DbContext type, but it hadn't hit me that it would need to cast to the base type. Works perfectly, thanks! (PS - could you be a bit quicker next time?)